# What is the Unity way to ensure that calling "initializing" events in managers happen after subscribing to them?

Tags: unity, initialization

Example of the situation from the title:

I have manager `A` and `B`.

I subscribe to `B`'s event: `E`, in `A`'s `Start` function.

I invoke `E` in `B`'s `Start` function.

If `A`'s `Start` function is called earlier then there is a problem: the initializing event has not yet been subscribed, therefore nothing is called.

What is "the Unity way" of solving this?

Using `Awake` just to solve this seems like an overkill for me,
same with setting Script Execution Order".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think using Awake is overkill? [The documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) says that this is one of the purposes of Awake:

> you should use `Awake` to set up references between scripts, and use `Start`, which is called after all `Awake` calls are finished, to pass any information back and forth.

Setting up event subscriptions is a perfect example of "setting up references between scripts".

So "the Unity way" is to set up all your event subscriptions in `Awake` and then invoke any initialization events in `Start`.

---

There were some comments asking what to do if two phases of initialization isn't enough. Perhaps because you have event subscriptions which can not be set up before some initialization event has happened and which have handlers which then invoke initialization events of their own.

If that's the case: Are you sure that using events is even the right architectural pattern for all of the things you are trying to do? The reason why you use events is usually because you can't predict if and when things are going to happen. With initialization, that's not the case. You know it's going to happen exactly once and it's going to happen at startup.

So when you have complex dependencies in your game state initialization, then perhaps events are not actually the right tool for that. What you might actually need is a single, monolithic master initialization routine in form of a method which calls all the initialization steps of your game state in a deterministic order.

"But what about loose coupling" you ask? Well, when your code relies on objects A and B being initialized in a specific order, then you already have a tight coupling between A and B. So you already lost that battle.